# MySQL query to get common or duplicate values from different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns, one column (AffiliationCountry) shows the countries and the other column (ArtSubareaKeyword) shows the subject areas in related countries with comma-separated values.

I want to extract the subject area which is repeating for a country the same country one or more times and save it in a new column with the name "MostPopularSubjectArea".

**Table with values:**

As you can see in the table that a country is repeating and its values are also repeating.

| AffiliationCountry | ArtSubareaKeyword1 | ArtSubareaKeyword1 | ArtSubareaKeyword1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | Cell membranes | Cell staining | Coimmunoprecipitation |
| Kazakhstan | Factor analysis | Human performance | Immunofluorescence |
| Japan | Bone marrow | Diagnostic medicine | Genetic loci |
| Kazakhstan | Drug research | Factor analysis | Human performance |

**Results that are required:**

I want a SQL query that can store for that country a new column that stores the common subjects area which is occurring more.

| AffiliationCountry | MostPopularSubjectArea |
| --- | --- |
| Kazakhstan | Human performance |

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store multiple values in a string.  That is not the SQL way to store data.

Comment: take a look at this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Is it acceptable to separate values in different columns and do what I want? What is your opinion? I mean will it work for this question ?

Comment: I have edited my Table you can see table, if any other changes are required please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Any kind of help from you guys will be very precious for me :) Really.

Comment: Spreading an array across columns is also a bad schema design.  Make another table with 2 columns:  AffiliationCountry and Keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the table, you can select the pair of columns, union them and find the count using group by:

```
select 
t1.affiliation_country, t1.keyword, count(t1.keyword) as count_keyword
from
(
    select affiliation_country, lower(artsubareakeyword1) keyword from affliation_details
    union all
    select affiliation_country, lower(artsubareakeyword2) from affliation_details
    union all
    select affiliation_country, lower(artsubareakeyword3) from affliation_details
) t1
group by
t1.affiliation_country, t1.keyword
order by
count(t1.keyword) desc
```

Query Reference(Fiddle): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25bded45786a85f6740902699e633846

Updated Query:

```
with affiliation_details as
(
select 
t1.affiliation_country, t1.keyword, count(t1.keyword) as count_keyword
from
(
select affiliation_country, lower(artsubareakeyword1) keyword from affliation_details
union all
select affiliation_country, lower(artsubareakeyword2) from affliation_details
union all
select affiliation_country, lower(artsubareakeyword3) from affliation_details
) t1
group by
t1.affiliation_country, t1.keyword
order by
count(t1.keyword) desc
)

select 
  distinct affiliation_country
from
  affiliation_details
where
  count_keyword in (
    select 
      max(count_keyword) 
    from 
      affiliation_details
  )
```